# Looking for an iOS framework to pay off user services

Tags: ios, online-payment

How can I transfer money to some of my users? I.e. on airbnb they collect bank card info and transfere money via it for hosts who rent out their room. Is it any existing framework in iOS platform?

Comment: Check out Stripe.